# Javascript - Checkboxes to hide columns

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with some JS code that hides columns based off the state of a checkbox, and I'm hoping to get some help.

The check boxes are in a table.  The table has multiple rows.  eg:

```
1, 2
3, 4
```

Those check boxes correspond to columns in another maintable.  That maintable is a single row across.  eg: 1, 2, 3, 4

When I uncheck boxes 1 & 2 from the the table, it hides row 1 & 2 from the main table.  But if I uncheck boxes 3 & 4, it also hides row 1 & 2.

If the check boxes from the table are on a single line, then they hide all the columns as intended.  But because they are broken up via table-row, there is an issue.

```
$(function() {
$("#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).parent().index()+1,
        col = $("#table tr th:nth-child("+id+"), #table tr td:nth-child("+id+")");
    $(this).is(":checked") ? col.show() : col.hide();
}).prop("checked", true).change();
```

});

Here is a fiddle.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/o6e3pc3a/7/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the table rows when you call to `$(this).parent().index()+1` beacause you have the `<td>` tag in two rows which means that it is going to return the position inside `<tr>` and in every new `<tr>` the count start in 1 again.

**You have two solutions for that:**

1- You can put all the checkboxes inside one row:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="eventid" />Name</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="groupid" />ID</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="pathfile" />Type</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="filesize" />Number</td>
</tr>
```

Here's an example [JS Fiddle Example 1](https://jsfiddle.net/o6e3pc3a/11/)

2- Or you can just add an attribute `data-id` with the value of the column's position:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="1" name="option1" value="eventid" />Name</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="2" name="option2" value="groupid" />ID</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="3" name="option3" value="pathfile" />Type</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="4" name="option4" value="filesize" />Number</td>
</tr>
```

And then catch it in js:

```
$(function() {
    $("#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(e) {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            col = $("#table tr th:nth-child("+id+"), #table tr td:nth-child("+id+")");
        $(this).is(":checked") ? col.show() : col.hide();
    }).prop("checked", true).change();   
});
```

Here's an example [JS Fiddle Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/o6e3pc3a/9/)

If you don't mind the style of the page I recommend de first one. If not, the second one is more dynamic

Comment: Slight advice for answering, you can use `---` on a single line to add barred text to easily highlight sections, and text on the line above the `---` to set a bold and larger title.

Comment: YES!  Thank you!  Example #2 works best for my need and is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The index is 'incorrect' because you have the checkboxes split into two table rows.
Put the checkboxes in one row `<tr>` and they work correctly.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="eventid" />Name</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="groupid" />ID</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="pathfile" />Type</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="filesize" />Number</td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o6e3pc3a/8/

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but the page layout shows the check-boxes in a table with multiple rows.  How can I get the JS to see the entire table?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @joac omf .
Because the `<chekcbox>` are the childen of `<td>` tags. They are not sibling, so the index is incorrect.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: I'm sorry. 
I just came to this site short time .